# Keyboard shortcut for Run As -> Android JUnit Test in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, shortcut, robotium

Anybody figured out the keyboard equivalent of this menu?

[image: The menu I would like to have a keyboard shortcut for]

I have been using this menu on test cases infused with Robotium with class signatures like:

```
public class AccountTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> { ... }
```

Somehow, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> just doesn't quite do the same thing even if you select the Android JUnit Runner in the dialog that pops up...

The similar Run As -> Android Application has a tricky shortcut of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> when launching every other conceivable type of runnable begins with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, so there is hope.

Answer (score 5):

*`Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Always launch the previously launched application.`*

Run the test case, either the whole thing, or a particular test method, once. It then becomes available to run again in the history. Press the Run or Debug button's drop down menu. Select the configuration you want to run.
From then on, <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (debug or run) rinses and repeats the exact same thing again.

type type type, <kbd>F11</kbd>, observe results, type type type. No mouse. Very productive.

Answer (score 3):

On my macbook I'm using Shift-Command-Fn-F11.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a similar shortcut but for TestNG, in my case, the shortcut is `SHIFT + ALT + X, G`

So when I press `SHIFT + ALT + X`, I get a small window at bottom right side as:

[image]

Once I see this window on the bottom right, as I hit the key `G`, it launches TestNG Suite as expected.